# Angularjs Bootstrap Year and Month picker

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In **Angularjs** I need **Month** and **Year picker**

I checked lot of things will be month year and date also

once after select month i need to create div based on selected month date

Answer (score 0):

I dont think bootstrap is the right choice here.

You can use [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) :)

Its a really neat feature and really easy to use.

Comment: is this Angularjs 1 version

Comment: Yes AngularJS always refers to version 1 :)